# Trim string from center, starting with spaces

Tags: string, actionscript-3, trim

I have an odd question.

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
/          /    \          \
```

What I want to do is trim the string *from the center* to a certain length, but primarily trimming spaces and then other characters.

For example, if I wanted to trim that string to 10 characters, it might look like this:

```
/   /\   \
```

But then if I want to reduce it further, to 4 characters, it might look like this:

```
//\\
```

And then finally, once I get down to no spaces left in the string, I want to trim from the center, but remove all characters. So if I want my string to now become only 2 characters, it might look like this:

```
/\
```

And if I have a string like this:

```
    b  a ab
```

And I trim it to 2 characters using  this function, it would look like this:

```
aa
```

Is this possible, and if so, ***how***?

Comment: Does this have a practical use, or is it just some kind of challenge?

Comment: @MartyWallace It does have a practical use for something I am making

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough time to go into great detail with code at this moment, but I am thinking something along the lines of:

- Break the string into two halves.
- Reverse the first half.
- Begin removing whitespace characters from the left of both strings, followed by non-whitespace characters if more truncation is desired.
- Reverse the first half again.
- Join it to the front of the second half to get the result.